# Segmentation fault of Bumblebee2

Tags: ros, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, all,

I am trying to use bumblebee2.
After roslaunch bumblebee2 Bumblebee2.launch, the error is
Segmentation fault, stopping camera driver.
Could someone help me? Thank you

---

memcpy(&left_cam_info_.K[0], &left_K_data[0], sizeof(left_K_data));

---

### ERROR

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::TransportLoadException'

what():  Unable to load plugin for transport 'raw', error string:

According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/raw_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/compressed_sub image_transport/theora_sub raw_sub

[stereo_image_proc-3] process has died [pid 8686, exit code -6].
log files: /home/nutan/.ros/log/d385af58-97bb-11e0-b1e7-00e081b5d370/stereo_image_proc-3*.log

### LOG

stereo_image_proc-3.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10129/segmentation-fault-of-bumblebee2/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-02**:
You might want to reformat that. (use the edit link below your post)

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-06-02**:
I manage to find out what causes the error. The error was due to memcpy the calibration data into the cam_info. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The stereo_image_proc error suggests that you have incompatible C-turtle and Diamondback stack versions mixed together. Can you check the output of:

```
rosversion image_common
rosversion image_pipeline
rosversion image_transport_plugins
```

They should all be 1.4.x.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi Nutan,

the bumblebee2 node contains a bug when setting the CameraInfo on diamondback.

to fix this problem you will need to edit 2 things in the file: "bumblebee2.cpp"
the first thing that needs to be done is to resize left_cam_info_.D (left_cam_info_.D.resize(5);) and right_cam_info_.D (right_cam_info_.D.resize(5);)

the second thing that needs to be done is to set the camera info distortion_model to plumb_bob. if this isn't done stereo_camera_proc wont be able to process the image. (right_cam_info_.distortion_model = left_cam_info_.distortion_model = "plumb_bob";)

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-06-23**:
i think you should ask the question about stereo_image_proc in a new question so it gets recorded for everyone. i cant help you with that (never ran into that problem)

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-06-15**:
I am sorry. The previous error was because of the stereo_proc_image process dying. I have already edit and upload the new error above.

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-06-11**:
the disparity image is published by stereo_image_proc, so you always need to run that to get the disparity image. beside that can you check what images the bumblebee2 node publishes by using image_view to check both topics (see if it publishes anything)

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-06-09**:
After I added the resize and set the distortion_model for the cam info, the segmentation fault was gone. However, when I try to run the stereo view to get the disparity image, i only get3 blank windows with nothing being displayed. Then an error occurs. I pasted the error info and attached log file above.

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-06-09**:
no, you will need add those in the initialization of the class or beginning of the updateBumblebee2CalibrationData function. resize will ensure the array is large enough to contain the data your going to copy into it.

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-06-08**:
Hi Bram, Thaks. Do you mean replace " memcpy(&left_cam_info_.D[0], &left_D_data[0], sizeof(left_D_data)); " by "memcpy(&left_cam_info_.D.resize(5), &left_D_data[0], sizeof(left_D_data));" ?